# JSP code displays null even though attribute was sent

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I ran out of ideas. I printed my ArrayList books which I send from my Servlet and it is displaying null all the time. When I printed that array in Servlet it displays correct set of data. Maybe you can help me:
This is Servlet:

```
    private void listBookedPlaces(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

    // get list of booked places from db util
    List<Book> books = bookDbUtil.getBooks();

    // add booked places to the request
    request.setAttribute("BOOKED_LIST", books); // set Attribute  (-name "BOOKED_LIST", -value books);

    // send to JSP page (view)
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/list-book.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

}
```

and this is my JSP code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*, com.pbs.web.jdbc.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>PSBS - Booked Parking Spaces Tracker</title>
</head>
<%
    // "BOOKED-LIST" is attribiute name set in ControllerServlet
    List<Book> theBooks = 
            (List<Book>) request.getAttribute("BOOKED_LIST");                      
%>
<body>
    <%= theBooks %>
</body>
</html>
```

I think an error must be somwhere while dispatching or in the JSP itself.
I'm 100% sure that .jsp file name i provided is correct.
Any ideas?

Comment: The issue was in the different file. In index.html I forgot to add hidden data type which I use later to recognize if I shall just display the list, or update and displayed. If only displayed whole SQL query is omitted there is no input query, just query to get data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your project built using mvc concept? if so, then I assume you have a bean book class, maybe this is one of them :

```
public int getBookID() {
    return bookID;
}
```

then extract 'BOOKED_LIST' in your jsp as per method in bean :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*, com.pbs.web.jdbc.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>PSBS - Booked Parking Spaces Tracker</title>
</head>
<%
    // "BOOKED-LIST" is attribiute name set in ControllerServlet                      
%>
<body>
    <c:forEach var="bookBean" items="${BOOKED_LIST}">
        <tr>
            <td>${bookBean.getBookID()}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this code

```
 List<Book> theBooks = (List<Book>) request.getAttribute("BOOKED_LIST");
```

you are getting list not object.
You better use for loop to print object of list inside body like

```
<%
for (int i = 0; i < theBooks.size(); i++)
      {
         System.out.println(theBooks.get(i).toString());
      }
%>
```